# find all specific folders and zip them

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I want to find all folders with name 'test' and to zip them into single folder with different names, of course.

I managed to do some code:

```cs
$RootFolder = "E:\"
$var = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Recurse |
       where {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match 'test'}

#this is assembly for zip functionality
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"

foreach ($dir in $var) {
    $destination = "E:\zip\test" + $dir.Name + ".zip"

    if (Test-Path $destination) {Remove-Item $destination}

    [IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($dir.PSPath, $destination)
}
```

It gives me an error:

> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."

I want to know, what is the right way to pass path of my `$dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PSPath` property returned from `Get-ChildItem` is prefixed with the `PSProvider`. The [`CreateFromDirectory()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx) takes two strings; the first is `sourceDirectoryName` for which you could use `Fullname` from your object.

```
$RootFolder = "E:\"
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -And
    $_.BaseName -Match 'test'
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

foreach ($Directory in $Directories) {
    $Destination = "E:\zip\test$($Directory.name).zip"

    If (Test-path $Destination) {
        Remove-Item $Destination
    }

    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Directory.Fullname, $Destination) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `Fullname` propery was confusing to me, I didn't suspect that is actually a path!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using v5, I would suggest using the [Commandlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive)

If you don't want to use the commandlet you can use this:

```
$FullName = "Path\FileName"
$Name = CompressedFileName
$ZipFile = "Path\ZipFileName"
$Zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($ZipFile,'Update')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($Zip,$FullName,$Name,"optimal")
$Zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: I like Dispose method, I will give it a try! Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder structure like this:

```
- Folder1
 -- Test
- Folder2
 -- Test
- Folder3
 -- Test
```

You can do this:

```
gci -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'test*' | % {
    Compress-Archive "$($_.FullName)\**" "$($_.FullName -replace '\\|:', '.' ).zip"
}
```

And you will get:

D..Dropbox.Projects.StackOverflow-Posh.ZipFolders.Folder1.Test.zip
D..Dropbox.Projects.StackOverflow-Posh.ZipFolders.Folder2.Test.zip
D..Dropbox.Projects.StackOverflow-Posh.ZipFolders.Folder3.Test.zip

Or if you want to preserve the directory structure inside your zips:

```
gci -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'test*' | % {
        Compress-Archive $_.FullName "$($_.FullName -replace '\\|:', '.' ).zip"
    }
```